# FixedUpdate() Not Being Called

Tags: unity, c#

I'm following a tutorial for making a simple shooter in Unity, but I have a problem. FixedUpdate() is never being called. I tested Update(), and it was being called as it should be. Normally I would usually just use Update(), but everyone says FixedUpdate() should be used. This is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6f;

    Vector3 movement;
    Animator anim;
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;
    int floorMask;
    float camRayLength = 100f;

    void Awake()
    {
        floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Floor");
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpate()
    {
        Debug.Log("fixedUpdate hit");
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Debug.Log(h);
        Debug.Log(v);

        Move(h, v);
        Turning();
        Animating(h, v);
    }

    void Move(float h, float v)
    {

        movement.Set(h, 0f, v);
        movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
    }

    void Turning()
    {
        Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit floorHit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask))
        {
            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
            playerToMouse.y = 0f;

            Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
        }
    }

    void Animating(float h, float v)
    {
        bool walking = h != 0f || v != 0f;
        anim.SetBool("IsWalking", walking);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have misspelling! `FixedUpate` is wrong `FixedUpdate` is correct add 'd'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As addressed in the comments, you *must* use correct spelling, when calling these methods. They are called, internally, so miss-spelt methods will not be called.

Your calling FixedUpate; you need to call FixedUp**d**ate.